# Any downside to using Multer middleware on my whole express app?

Tags: node.js, express

Early on in my Express app, I define Multer middleware to be used like this:

```
const multer = require('multer');
app.post('*', multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() }).any());
```

I'm using multer for file uploads.

The majority of my post request to my app will not require any file uploads and so that middleware is mostly useless most of the time.

Is there any downside or danger to using it like this, or is there some reason why I should just be applying the middleware to post requests that require file uploads?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to not use multer as a middleware for the whole app. 
Using multer as a middleware would just be acting as a security threat for your app.

For example. You had two routes:

i. /register (requires an image upload as avatar)

ii. /login (doesnt require any file upload)

Any malicious user could easily use /login to upload malicious files into your destination folder in the app and could possibly act as a huge threat.

Only using the multer middleware in routes where you would do a file upload helps mitigate the risk to uploading unwanted and/or malicious files into the server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But wouldn't I have to manually implement something to save the file into the folder with /login? At the moment, file uploads are taken care of manually in the path that I use it - I get the file data and decide what to do with it (and I don't actually save a physical file at all, I take the data and send it to a blob storage service). Or will multer somehow make it so that files do automatically save somewhere?

Comment: You can send a "POST" request to the endpoint and multer will save the file to the location you specified while initializing multer, i.e let x = multer({dest: "/home"}). So the file sent will be saved in destination home automatically.

Comment: okay that's interesting. The way that I've initialized Multer, then, might actually mean I don't have to worry about that. `multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() })` -- I think this means that my image doesn't save when multer handles it - it stores the buffer in memory and doesn't save a file until I do something manually with the buffer.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it works. No idea. But just to let you know, letting everyone post random data to any of your endpoints is a bad idea.

Comment: Is there any example type documentation, where file uploads are done using Angular and Node (and a SQL Database), but without using Multer?